# How to put an existing record in the MongoDB so that no new document is created?

Tags: mongodb, restheart

How to efficiently post a document to MongoDB without checking if it is already in the collection. Currently, in my JAVA code, I am checking for the existence of document first and then if it is not where I post it. It seems this is very slow because for every document I am placing two queries.

Can't it be possible to just post the document and MongoDB handle it automatically that if there is already an existing document, just overwrite it else create a new document?

My document structure:

```
{
    "_id": "my unique id string",
    "name": "name1",
    "Address":{
       "street": "street 1",
       "country": "NZ",
    }
}
```

I am checking the existence of a document by comparing the "_id" field.

Comment: i guess this is what you are seeking for `db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, options)`

Comment: @AlpitAnand I am posting the content via RESTHeart, not via Mongo console. So, I am not sure how to execute your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With RESTHeart all write requests have *upsert semantic*: a request inserts a document into the collection (if it does not already exist) or updates it (if it does).

In order to avoid a document to be updated if it already exists, you can use the [ETag](https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/x/hICM) checking feature of RESTHeart.

A request with the **If-Match** header only updates an existing document if its *_etag* property matches the specified value.

The following request fails with *412 Precondition Failed* status code if the document `/db/coll/docid` exists:

```
POST /db/coll { "_id": "docid", "name": "name1", .. } If-Match:"etag"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the filter by which you find the document, then find and update the document. Using Java driver, you could do it like this:

```
Document filter = new Document("_id", "my unique id string");
Document update = new Document("name", "name1")
                     .append("Address", "<other fields>");
Document oldDocument = database
                     .getCollection("collectionName")
                     .findOneAndUpdate(filter, update);
```

`oldDocument` will be null if **no** document matched the filter.

If you would like to insert the document in case it didn't exist, then you should **upsert**:

```
UpdateOptions uo = new UpdateOptions().upsert(true);
database.getCollection("collectionName")
             .updateOne(filter, update, uo);
```

The last method call will return a result object that will give you the new `ID` if the document was created.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RESTHeart then PUT and POST methods implement the [Mongodb's upsert semantics](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) by default. See the [Write Requests](https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/RH/pages/21364773/Write+Requests#WriteRequests-Writeverbs) section in the docs.